# Why won't applications in Program Files run using os.execute in lua?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to run an executable using Lua's `os.execute()` function. If I do something like the following it does not work:

```
os.execute("C:\\\Program Files\\\Movie Maker\\\moviemk.exe")
```

However, if I put my lua file in the same path that `moviemk.exe` is in then it can call it.

Any ideas why this may be?

P.S. I'm using Windows XP SP3

Comment: Three backslashes is too much. You might have more luck if you reduce them to two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 os.execute("C:\\Program Files\\Movie Maker\\moviemk.exe")
```

or:

```
 os.execute("C:/Program Files/Movie Maker/moviemk.exe")
```

The '\' character is used for escape characters in Lua.

Comment: Actually, I think just figured it out. I did os.execute('C:\\\Program Files\\\Movie Maker\\\moviemk.exe"') ... the extra '' around the "" seems to do the trick. Seems strange to me though.

Comment: It may be the spaces in some of the file names. Windows struggles with those form time to time.

Answer (score 16):

This is a classic problem with the command shell. It isn't really a Windows specific problem, except that on *nix, people never really got into the habit of putting spaces in file names, and Windows puts spaces in several default system places such as `C:\Program Files`.

What is happening is that `os.execute(str)` is implemented in terms of the ANSI C function `system(str)`, which on Windows tries to duplicate the effect of typing `"cmd /C "..str` to the command prompt. (On *nix, it uses /bin/sh -c instead of cmd /C.)

The classic problem is that this has to split the complete command string at whitespace to decide what program to run, and what its arguments are.

Your original example: `os.execute("C:\\Program Files\\Movie Maker\\moviemk.exe")` effectively became `cmd /c c:\program files\movie maker\moviemk.exe`, which after splitting it up on whitespace, CMD tried to find a program named `c:\program` to execute with arguments named `files\movie` and `maker\moviemk.exe`. This isn't what you intended.

The solution is to be much more defensive about quoting.

I would write this as:

```
os.execute [["C:\Program Files\Movie Maker\Moviemk.exe"]]
```

If there were additional command line arguments to be supplied, I would use double-quotes around each, and a single space between arguments. Using the long string syntax `[[...]]` has the advantage that backslash isn't a special character, so you don't need extra leaning toothpicks making it harder to read the string literal.

Using double quotes around each argument should work on both Windows and *nix, although it is harder to find commands that are the same on both platforms, of course.

One other detail to be aware of is that `\Programs Files` might not be on `C:`. There might not even be a disk named `C:`. (My work PC boots from `E:` and I find more buggy programs that way.) The easiest way to learn the correct pathname is to just use the environment variable `ProgramFiles`. There are many other ways.