# Lua and the white spaces of the OS. How to solve?

Tags: lua, whitespace

I'm trying to execute a command with `io.popen` in Lua, but the path contains white spaces. I've tested with `\\`, combinations of  `\"\'`, and so on. How to solve this, because the command always returns "C:\Program" not recognized....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:[Why won't applications in Program Files run using os.execute in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587788/why-wont-applications-in-program-files-run-using-os-execute-in-lua)

the [[ ]]  method works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
io.popen([[C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/vcpackages/vcbuild.exe]], "r")
```

Note that you were calling the function with one argument that looked like this:

`"C:/.../vcbuild.exe", "r"`

Answer (score -1):

```
local exe_path = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/vcpackages/vcbuild.exe"'

io.popen(exe_path, "r")
```