# Lua and the white spaces in an OS

Tags: lua, whitespace

After [reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587788/why-wont-applications-in-program-files-run-using-os-execute-in-lua), I used `[[ ]]` to put commands into the system. The problem is the following: The same structure:

```
local Program = [["c:\Archivos de programa\Automated QA\TestComplete 8\Bin\TestComplete.exe" ]];
local testcase = [["C:\svn_test\trunk\Automation\XMM\XMM.pjs" ]];
local options = [[/r /exit /p:XMMGeneralTest /t:"Script|main|Main" ]];

local cmd = Program..testcase..options;
print(cmd);
os.execute(cmd);

local tcLog = [[ C:\svn_test\trunk\Automation\XTYLE\XTyleGeneralTest\Log\11_04_2011_12_40_06_264\*]];
local zippedFile = "11_04_2011_12_40_06_264.7z ";
local sevenZip = [["c:\Archivos de Programa\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z ]];

local cmd = sevenZip..zippedFile..tcLog;
print(cmd);
os.execute(cmd);
```

The same code produce different results. The first one doesn't run:

```
"c:\Archivos" not recognized as internal command or external,
program...
```

The second one runs perfectly.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I have no idea if this is the cause, but wouldn't you need in the first case spaces between the tree strings?

Comment: Yeah, I miss this spaces when editting this post, but this is not the reason to this error :(

Comment: I have no windows here, so I can't really test this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also don't have a windows system to test with, so this is just a guess:

Try replacing this:

```
local Program = [["c:\Archivos de programa\Automated QA\TestComplete 8\Bin\TestComplete.exe" ]];
```

with this:

```
local Program = [[c:\\Archivos\ de\ programa\\Automated\ QA\\TestComplete\ 8\\Bin\\TestComplete.exe ]];
```

I fear that it won't work since the `[[` and `]]` will block the interpretation of the escapes, but that may change as it goes from one variable to another and then to the `os.execute`.  The other option is to use the windows version of these files without spaces, e.g.:

```
local Program = [[c:\Archiv~1\Automa~1\TestCo~1\Bin\TestComplete.exe ]];
```

Comment: local Program = [[c:\Archiv~1\Automa~1\TestCo~1\Bin\TestComplete.exe ]]; This works fine, and It'll work until I fiond a better solution :)

Comment: Note that it is not a Lua problem. Try running the same command from cmd shell. You have to escape spaces.