# How to run exe file exist in the same folder through Lua application?

Tags: lua

I can't find this I want to make code that can run exe file in the same folder
without static path.
As example if the file name is application.exe then I want to run the file
and if not exist error message pop up cant find application.exe
any help with this please?
this can be done in vb but I don't know if that can be done too in lua?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure how it works on Windows, but on Linux this works fine:

```
os.execute("./foo")
```

There's some more info on Lua on Windows on [Lua Unofficial FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.40).

**Update:** You might also want to read [How to execute an external command](http://www.luafaq.org/#T3.2) on LuaFAQ. There is some interesting information on executing GUI programs on Windows, as well as a link to [Launching processes with winapi](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/api.html#Launching_processes).

**Update 2:** I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3589108/295262

It's regarding the opposite question, full path. According to it, `os.execute "application.exe"` will work in the same directory, although you might want to try one of the fancier ways from LuaFAQ.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, the **os.execute()** function allow you to run a system command into the path of lua execution.

If you want to get the output, you can use **io.popen()** instead :

```
local f = io.popen("application.exe","r")
print(f:read("*a"))
```